# Why do we describe a problem or experience as "hairy"?

Tags: expressions, slang, history

I'm curious about the use/history of "hairy", as in *Golly Dan, that was a pretty hairy math exam, wasn't it?*

My dictionary sources identify two definitions unrelated to hair: the first can be summarized as "causing fright or anxiety", which I semi-confidently assume relates to "hair-raising"; the other is "difficult to deal with or comprehend" (from Merriam Webster). It's this latter that I'm curious about.

How did we come to say that something difficult is "hairy"?

Comment: I found that hairy became recognized as slang for difficult around 1848, but I couldn't find much else. I do know that hairy is used in mainstream British English to describe something difficult.

Comment: It's only a guess, but I wonder if it's related to a "tangled mess" (or a "rat's nest") that requires a lot of unraveling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Robert Hendrickson, *The Facts on File Encyclopedia of Word and Phrase Origins* (1997) offers this analysis:

> **hairy.** *Hairy*, as slang for unpleasant or rough, seems to be of Army origin, from about 1935, when a *hairy patrol* was an unpleasant one that met with resistance. Its origin is unknown, but the word may have something to do with *to make one's hair stand on end* and "scary." Another possibility, a longshot, is the English expression *hairy at the heel*, common in the late 19th century. A horse with hair about the heels or fetlocks was an underbred one, so the expression was used figuratively for an ill-bred, bad-mannered, thoroughly unpleasant person, as was *hairy*.

Eric Partridge, *A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English* (1961) confirms that the meaning of "hairy about the fetlocks," is "ill-bred, bad-mannered," and says that it comes "from the stables"; but he distinguishes that meaning of *hairy* (which he traces to the late 1890s) from the earliest meaning—"difficult"—which he says comes from Oxford University, circa 1850–1900.

An earlier work by Partridge, [*Slang To-day and Yesterday*](https://books.google.com/books?id=I3BKCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA422&dq=%22amen+corner+a+church%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit3_aS5ITKAhVO8GMKHQNJDg8Q6AEIQTAD#v=onepage&q=hairy&f=false) (1933) puts the dates for *hairy* as "difficult" as 1840–1870), suggesting that it had fallen into disuse by the turn of twentieth century:

> **Hairy.** Difficult : Oxford, 1840–1870. N., a draught horse: C[entury] 20.

John Farmer & William Henley, [*Slang and Its Analogues Past and Present*](https://books.google.com/books?id=n7FZAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA248&dq=%22Hairy,+adj.+(Oxford+University)%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv_J3Q_9XsAhUUFzQIHYweBSYQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Hairy%2C%20adj.%20(Oxford%20University)%22&f=false) (1893), also list "difficult" as the earliest slang meaning of *hairy*, and offer two early instances of that usage:

> **Hairy,** *adj.* (Oxford University).—**1.** Difficult
>
> [Example:] *d.* 1861. Arthur Clough, *Long Vacation Pastoral*. Three weeks hence we return to the shop and the wash-hand-stand-bason, Three weeks hence unbury Thicksides and HAIRY Aldrich.
>
> [Example:] 1864. *The Press*, 12 Nov. HAIRY for difficult is a characteristic epithet.

Other nineteenth-century meanings of *hairy* reported in Farmer & Henley include "Splendid; famous; conspicuous; uncommon" and [of women] "Desirable; full of sex."

None of the early editions of John Camden Hotten's *Slang Dictionary* (published in London between 1859 and 1874) contains any entry for *hairy*—even though *hairy* in the sense of "difficult" appears to be a survival of English university slang from roughly that era.

Answer (score 0):

I've been told that when you're depending on a rope for whatever reason and it has frayed in a place it looks 'hairy'. Having a frayed rope you're climbing on would sure be 'hairy' I'd imagine.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide an actual source for this other than "I've been told..."

Answer (score -1):

I always believed it was a "harried" situation, and the pronunciation degraded had to "hairy".

har·ried
ˈharēd/
adjective
feeling strained as a result of having demands persistently made on one; harassed.

Answer (score -1):

*Haar* is a sea mist. If visibility is poor due mist, or hair, then it is a bit risky or hairy to sail.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_(fog)):

> In meteorology, **haar** is a cold sea fog. It usually occurs on the east coast of England or Scotland between April and September, when warm air passes over the cold North Sea.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: I think you mean *haar*, not hair.

Comment: Yes, it is haar.  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/haar